# HttpClient. ReadAsStreamAsync throws "The stream was already consumed. It cannot be read again"

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I have a client method

```cs
var httpClientFactory = ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://example.com");

using var multipartContent = new MultipartFormDataContent
{
    { await CreateFileContent(statisticDataStream, "text/csv"), "data_file", Path.GetFileName($"data.file.{Guid.NewGuid()}.csv") },
    { await CreateFileContent(metaDataStream, "application/json"), "meta_file", Path.GetFileName($"meta.file.{Guid.NewGuid()}.csv") }
};

using var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "task");
request.Content = multipartContent;
request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

try
{
    using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var serrializer = GetSerializer();
        var responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(cancellationToken); // Exception here!
        return ReadFromJsonStream<TaskCreatedResult>(responseStream, serrializer)!;
    }
}

catch (Exception ex) {
    throw;
}
```

I can use it to send request to create task in runner.
And it works. I can see it in dashboard. New task are created.

But when line with reading response as stream is executed (to get task id) it throws an exception.

```
EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: The stream was already consumed. It cannot be read again.
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent.ConsumeStream()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent.CreateContentReadStreamAsync()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CreateContentReadStreamAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.ReadAsStreamAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
...
```

I spent hours looking for the cause and trying to fix the problem experimentally, but there is too little information on the Internet about this. This problem bothers me.

Anyone have the same problem as me?
Any ideas of how can I fix it?
10q.

Comment: Do you have any delegating handlers in the chain?

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama yes. The problem was handler for logging requests and responses